# Two styles of document - how to switch

Tags: templates, document-classes

The two following pdfs are both typeset in LaTeX but clearly they differ in style. Default package I am using yields the same result as seen in second link. What should I do in order to get the style as in the first pdf?

https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/meh/notes4.pdf

http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_1.pdf

Comment: You can contact the authors for a sample. The whole point of LaTeX is creating those consistent output. What you ask is equivalent to *how to LaTeX?*.

Comment: To me the target style looks similar to the [`amsart`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart?lang=en) class. But perhaps the footer "Typeset by [AMS-TeX](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amstex)" could lead to more specific information. (Or ask the authors.)

Comment: It is close to impossible to look at a document and state how it is set up. And in most cases it is not what you want to do. Instead you want to have a look on your document and think how you would like to change it. For example, if you want the equation numbers to the right as in this document you can set the option `leqno` to either `amsmath`or the document class. The text size can be changed by the packet `geometry`and the headers by `fancyhdr`. Most such things you can easily find by web search, and the documentation for the packets also pops up there. But take one step at a time.

Comment: Your first sentence is false, the first one is not set with latex but with amstex, which is a different, more or less obsolete, format.  `amsart` class (including `amsmath`) is more or less a re-implementation of amstex for latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to add an answer here? Or do something else?

Answer (score 3):

Your assertion that the documents were set with latex is not correct, the first one is not set with latex but with amstex, which is a different, more or less obsolete, format.

The `amsart` class (including `amsmath`) is more or less a re-implementation of amstex for latex, so I would use that.